# Highcharts area chart with fill color relative to an overlapped line chart

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts, styling

Is there a mechanism in Highcharts to have an area chart show different color based on the position relative to an overlapped line chart, such as in the following?

[image: Red and green area chart relative to line chart]

The color of the area chart is relative to the line chart, with one key complication being that they may cross between two points. We're thinking we may be able to do this based on the "[Area with missing points](https://www.highcharts.com/demo/area-missing/gray)" example but that will require us to do the calculation of exact crossing point, which we'd rather offload if possible.

Thanks!

Comment: see this https://www.highcharts.com/demo/area-negative and   [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/deep3015/85t1opLv/) sample

Comment: @Deep3015, thanks, that's in the right direction but not quite the same. In our target chart the "negative" threshold changes. I checked Highcharts API and `threshold` only supports a single number.

Comment: Can you make a live example?

Comment: @SamuelNeff Have you find any solution? I am facing the same problem

Comment: @Inbal I switched to D3.

Comment: @Inbal I'll elaborate a bit. I was able to accomplish this in D3. It involved many layers of almost the same chart above and below the various lines, some red, some green, with many layers of masks. The biggest problem was the threshold line is a step chart and the other lines are line charts, so you end up with situations where both lines go from say 100 to 110, but the line chart goes diagonally from 100 to 110 and the threshold line goes straight at 100 and then jumps to 110. Several layers just to address this issue and the small triangles of wrong color that resulted from this issue.